# Add a popup in Drupal 8 admin

Tags: drupal, admin, drupal-8

I want to create a popup that display example of possible usable tag in a textarea, I need it to be displayed on every content edition page on the admin.

What do I need to do to have that kind of block in the admin content edition page ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would create a module with:

- A `twig` file containing the contents of the dialog.
- A small JS file to show the dialog, using the `jquery.dialog library` included in Drupal 8.
- Implement a `hook_from_alter` to attach the changes based on the `form_id`s.

Like the following, which works on node edit forms, but is not thoroughly tested:

file: templates/popuptag.html.twig

```
<div style="display: none;">
  <div id="popuptag-dialog" title="Tag Usage">
   <p>The tag can be used at vero eos et accusamus et iusto odio
     dignissimos ducimus qui blanditiis praesentium voluptatum
     deleniti atque corrupti quos dolores et quas molestias
     excepturi sint occaecati cupiditate non provident, similique sunt.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

file: js/popuptag.dialog.js

```
(function ($) {
  'use strict';
  Drupal.behaviors.popuptag_dialog = {
    attach: function (context) {
      $( "#popuptag-dialog" ).dialog();
    }
  };
})(jQuery);
```

file: popuptag.module

```
/**
 * Implements hook_theme().
 */
function popuptag_theme() {
  return [
    'popuptag' => [
      'template'  => 'popuptag',
      'render element' => 'dialog',
    ],
  ];
}

/**
 * Implements hook_form_alter().
 */
function popuptag_form_alter(&$form, \Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface $form_state, $form_id) {
  // Add here other form_ids if needed
  if (in_array($form_id, ['node_page_edit_form'])) {
    $form['popuptag'] = [
      '#theme' => 'popuptag',
      '#form_id' => $form_id,
    ];
    $form["#attached"]["library"][] = 'popuptag/dialog';
  }

}
```

file: popuptag.libraries.yml

```
dialog:
  js:
    js/popuptag.dialog.js: { minified: true }
  dependencies:
    - core/drupal.dialog
```

file: popuptag.info.yml

```
name: 'popuptag'
type: module
description: 'popuptag'
core: 8.x
package: 'Custom'
```

Comment: Exactly what I needed thanks for de detailed explanation